# How to delete a certain data in the Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing a social networking app, where users can follow other users and like their posts, comments ...
Whenever some user follows someone, it shows in a notification fragment in the other user account to inform him that he has a new follower.
The problem is that I couldn't remove the notification when the user hits unfollow. Here is what I have tried:

```
 if ( holder.btn_follow.getText().toString().equals("follow"))
 {
addNotifications(user.getId());
}
 else{
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications").child(user.getId()).removeValue();
   }
```

and here is how I added notification:

```
 private void addNotifications(String userid)
    {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications").child(userid);
        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("userid", firebaseUser.getUid());
        hashMap.put("text"," started following you");
        hashMap.put("postid","");
        hashMap.put("ispost",false);
        reference.push().setValue(hashMap);
    }
```

the problem with my code is that whenever the user unfollows someone, all the notifications from that user are deleted including his likes and comments. all I want is to delete "started following you".
Here is how it looks in the Firebase database.

[image]

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Comment: ohh, ok thank you. will not do it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Firebase Query refers to [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-queries), it will be something like this

```
Query queryRef = mReference.child("Notifications").child(userId).orderByChild("text").equalTo("start following you");

queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChild) {
      // snapshot.getRef().setValue(null);
      snapshot.getRef().remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: looks good I think it would work. but I don't have notificationId. I don't know how to access the data that I want to delete. this is the problem

Comment: in the database, it looks like there is a notificationid but I don't know why because I didn't assign it in my code

Comment: I updated. it should work even in this way